# Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed

Tags: c#, wpf

Refering to my last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568850/binding-in-combobox-xaml-wpf, I add a property FirstName in ClientBookKeepingViewModel. But now I got an error [image].

When I debug using breakpoint, the error comes from View.ShowDialog() [image]

My code is as follows:

```
  public int InsertClientBooking(int clientID, ClientBookKeepingViewModel k)
    {
        var client = new ClientBooking();

        using (var context = new ProActiveDBEntities())
        {
            client.ClientBookID = k.ClientBookKeepingID;
            client.ClientID = k.ClientID;
            client.EmployeeID = k.EmployeeID;
            client.WorkType = k.WorkType;
            client.DateRecorded = (DateTime)k.DateRecorded;
            client.BookingFormCompleted = k.BookingFormCompleted;
            client.TimeBudgetCompleted = k.TimeBudgetCompleted;
            client.ProposedCompletionDate = (DateTime)k.ProposedCompletionDate;
            client.IsCompleted = k.IsCompleted;
            client.FirstName = k.FirstName;

            context.Clients.First(i => i.ClientID == clientID).ClientBookings.Add(client);

            context.SaveChanges();

            return clientID;
        }
    }



      private void btnAddBooking_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientBookingView view = new ClientBookingView();
        ClientBookKeepingViewModel book = new ClientBookKeepingViewModel();

        book.Client = (ClientViewModel)this.DataContext;

        book.Mode = Mode.Add;
        view.DataContext = book;
        view.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**ClientBookingView.Xmal**

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="cbEmployeeName" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employee}}" 
 DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" 
 SelectedValue="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
 SelectedValuePath="FirstName"

<CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Name="dpBookingCompleted" Content="Yes" 
 IsChecked="{Binding BookingFormCompleted, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
/>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="9"  Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,5,20,0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Width="80" Margin="10" Height="25"
                    Command="{Binding ShowUpdateCommand}" 
                    Click="btnUpdate_Click">

            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mode}">
                            <DataTrigger.Value>
                                <enum:Mode>Add</enum:Mode>
                            </DataTrigger.Value>
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Add"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mode}">
                            <DataTrigger.Value>
                                <enum:Mode>Edit</enum:Mode>
                            </DataTrigger.Value>
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Save"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbEmployeeName, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbWorkType, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=dpDateRecord, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=dpProposedCompletionDate, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="10" Width="80" Height="25"
                    Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                    Click="btnCancel_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
```

**ClientBookListView**

```
 <ListView Name="lsvClientOwnerTypeList" Height="150" Width="700"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ClientBookList}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClientBook}">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource RowButtons}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Completed" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsCompleted}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Employee Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Work Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding WorkType}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date Recorded" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateRecorded, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Booking Form Completed" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BookingFormCompleted}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Time Budget Completed" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeBudgetCompleted}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Proposed Completion Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProposedCompletionDate, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}"  />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, do you see how you hardly ever get proper answers? This is because you keep asking questions that are very specific to *your* code and not general coding. Usually, we can only guess at what you've done. For example, between this question and the last one, you said that you just added a `FirstName` property to your `ClientBookKeepingViewModel` class, but you *must* have done other things too, because it is very unlikely that you would get those (or any) errors just by adding one property. So, my advice to you is for you to undo your changes until the project builds again.

Comment: hi daniel, sheridan is right. In order to answer this question and help you out more code is needed to be posted. can you pls post the code behind and xaml of your clientbookView?

Comment: @Sheridan. Hi Sheridan. Since the comments in last question are a bit longer, I am afraid people will be boring about that. So I create it as a new question linking to that question(actually it is the same question). I will post my code. Sorry for always asking low-quality questions.

Comment: @Daniel, I understand that you didn't want to extend the comments and that is good. However, my point is that you keep asking questions that are difficult for us to answer without asking you lots of questions in the comments... they're not 'low quality' questions... we just need more information. For example, your first error image says '...See the inner exception for details': What does the inner exception say? (Click the `View Detail` link in the Exception Popup to see the inner exception.)

Comment: @Sheridan. Thanks, Sheridan. Next time I will provide as more information as possible so that it is easy for you to answer the question, not just guess. A big sorry about that. I did check the ViewDetails, the inner exception says **{"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_ClientBooking_Employee\". The conflict occurred in database \"ProActiveDB\", table \"dbo.Employee\", column 'EmployeeID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}**, but I didnot find the problem. So I did not post this information. I use breakpoint you told me before getting the 2nd image.

Comment: @nit. Hi nit. Thanks for your suggestion. I will improve my skills in asking a question by providing as more related information as possible. I posted my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering in an answer so that the comments don't get too big.

Your inner Exception says:

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_ClientBooking_Employee\". The conflict occurred in database \"ProActiveDB\", table \"dbo.Employee\", column 'EmployeeID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

This means that you have a `Foreign Key` in your `Employee` table on the `EmployeeID` column called `FK_ClientBooking_Employee` and that there was a conflict when you tried to insert something into the database... if the conflict is with this column, then that normally means that you were trying to insert a row into another table that references this column in the `Employee` table, but your `EmployeeID` value was *not* in the `Employee` table.

UPDATE >>>

I'm not sure that you really needed to add that column into the database... that's what view models are for. You have the `FirstName` values in your `Employee` class (in C#), so all you needed to do was to add a new property into your view model class and fill it from your `Employee` class... *then*, you would be able to correctly bind to it.

Remember, the view model should hold all of the data that our view requires... but this *doesn't* mean that our view models have to match some database tables. In fact, there is often very little correlation between view models and database tables... it is the data type, or model, classes that match the database tables.

Comment: This is because I changed the database, I added FirstName in the table named "ClientBooking" (EmployeeId is a foreign key of this table).

Comment: It's not because you added a column... it *must* have happened when you tried to insert a row into this table with an invalid `EmployeeID` value that didn't exist in the `Employee` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. I found and solved the problem. It is due to my DB Primary Key set up. I also need to add a column FirstName in DB. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.